# Python / pandas: create a data frame's column and set it's value based on finding a column value in range of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas data frames,
First frame ip2CountryDF has 2M+ records of:

```
startIP, endIP, countryISO
16777216,16777471,US
16777472,16778239,CN
16778240,16779263,AU
```

IP Addresses in this data frame are represented as Integers for efficiency and matching purposes

Second frame inputDF has 60K+ records of:

```
sourceIP, eventTime, integerIP
114.119.157.43,01/Mar/2021,1920441643
193.205.128.7,01/Mar/2021,3251470343
193.205.128.7,01/Mar/2021,3251470343
193.205.128.7,01/Mar/2021,3251470343
```

> The data I have are all from publicly available datasets

What I'm trying to do is to identify source country for each row in inputDF based on the value in ip2CountryDF.

Ideally, I will pick inputDF['integerIP'] and get ip2CountryDF['countryISO'] where the integerIP from inputDF is in the range between ip2CountryDF['startIP'] and ip2CountryDF['endIP']

So far I got the data done using a for loop, it worked on the test set (searching data for 5 entries in inputDF) but when I hit a bigger dataset my machine fans pick up and after a couple of minutes I get no results and I cancel the job (which tells me how inefficient my code is), here is the code I use (inefficient but it works):

```
countryList = []
for index, row in inputDF.iterrows():
    integerIP   = row['integerIP']
    countryISO  = ip2CountryDF.loc[(integerIP >= ip2CountryDF['startIP']) & (integerIP <= ip2CountryDF['endIP']),'countryISO'].iloc[0]
    countryList.append(countryISO)
inputDF['countryISO']   = countryList
```

what I need help with, can this better be handled in a more efficient and more (panda-like) way, I was trying to use something like:

```
inputDF['countryISO'] = ip2CountryDF.loc[(inputDF['integerIP'] >= ip2CountryDF['startIP']) & (inputDF['integerIP'] <= ip2CountryDF['endIP']),'countryISO'].iloc[0]
```

Many thanks for taking the time to help me with this

Comment: @a-hadidi, I really need to know where the `ip2CountryDF` source file can be found. I'm pretty sure we can optimize to increase speed search.

Comment: @Corralien I got that one from ip2location, more specifically the ip2location-lite freely downloadable dataset at: https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country

Answer (score 1):

You are so closer. You just lack a call to "map" function.

Load the IpToCountry.csv (for documentation purpose):

```
IP2COUNTRY = "https://github.com/urbanadventurer/WhatWeb/raw/master/plugins/IpToCountry.csv"
db = pd.read_csv(IP2COUNTRY, header=None, usecols=[0, 1, 4],
                 names=["startIP", "endIP", "countryISO"], comment="#")
```

```
>>> db
           startIP       endIP countryISO
0                0    16777215         ZZ
1         16777216    16777471         AU
2         16777472    16777727         CN
3         16777728    16778239         CN
4         16778240    16779263         AU
...            ...         ...        ...
211757  4211081216  4227858431         ZZ
211758  4227858432  4244635647         ZZ
211759  4244635648  4261412863         ZZ
211760  4261412864  4278190079         ZZ
211761  4278190080  4294967295         ZZ

[211762 rows x 3 columns]
```

Create a function `ip2country` that for a decimal ip returns the corresponding iso country code:

```
def ip2country(ip: int):
    return db.loc[(db["startIP"] <= ip) & (ip <= db["endIP"]), "countryISO"].squeeze()


df["countryISO"] = df["integerIP"].map(ip2country)
```

```
>>> df
         sourceIP   eventTime   integerIP countryISO
0  114.119.157.43  2021-03-01  1920441643         SG
1   193.205.128.7  2021-03-01  3251470343         IT
2   193.205.128.7  2021-03-01  3251470343         IT
3   193.205.128.7  2021-03-01  3251470343         IT
```

**Performance**

For 10k ip addresses, results returned on average in 11.7s on a *2,5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7*.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"integerIP": np.random.randint(db["startIP"].min(), 
                                                   db["endIP"].max()+1,
                                                   size=10000)})

%timeit df1["integerIP"].map(ip2country)
11.7 s ± 489 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: It looks like your dfs are 200K and 10K whereas OP's are 2M and 60K. My laptop still struggles with the bigger dfs (10th gen 6-core i7 H-series, 32GB RAM).

Comment: How to get your ip2country database?

Comment: I used OP's 3x3 sample `ip2CountryDF` and concatenated into 2100000x3 with `ip2CountryDF = pd.concat([ip2CountryDF] * 700000)`

Comment: That surely works, I had to wait less time (do less things around the house until the code is done). Either my dataset is so big, or my machine does not have enough resources to deliver this faster...

Comment: @Corralien map function is what I was missing for sure. I am just learning pandas as I create my own code.